# Why assigning an Integer to a Double Attached Properties gives error?

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, dependency-properties, attached-properties

Assigning an Integer to a double is very much legal.

If we can do

```
double d = 3;
```

d is assigned `3.0`

but why this fails in Attached Properties?

**Scenario**

I created an Attached Property

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ActualWidthBeforeHidingProperty = 
       DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ActualWidthBeforeHiding", 
       typeof(double), typeof(MainWindow), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(0));

public static double GetActualWidthBeforeHiding(DependencyObject element)
    {
        if (element == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("element");
        }

        return Convert.ToDouble(element.GetValue(ActualWidthBeforeHidingProperty));
    }

public static void SetActualWidthBeforeHiding(DependencyObject element, double value)
    {
        if (element == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("element");
        }

        element.SetValue(ActualWidthBeforeHidingProperty, value);
    }
```

I compiled the code. There was no compiletime error.

But when I tried to run the application it gave error

[image]

In the above code I accidently assigned 0 in `new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(0)` and the code ran successfully.

But I was under the impression that you can assign a DataType having lesser precision (i.e. Integer) to a DataType having greater precision (i.e. 0.0 Double)?

Then Why this deflection from basic programming concept for Dependency Properties?

Comment: You might expect this to be, but this is not. You must assign the expected type. And if it is `double` either assign 3.0 or (double)3.

Comment: @bash.d: I know that but why this. Assigning integer to double is legal.

Comment: I ran into this error so often that I eventually edited my code snippets for dependency and attached properties so that the default value is always `default($type$)`...

Comment: @ThomasLevesque: How can you explain how to change that?

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal, using the code snippets manager (from the Tools menu), locate the NetFX30 snippets (`propa` and `propdp`); they're typically in *C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC#\Snippets\1033\NetFX30*. Edit them to remove the `defaultValue` literal declaration, and replace `$defaultValue$` with `default($type$)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of [boxing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx):

The parameter of the `FrameworkPropertyMetadata` constructor is declared as `object`, so when you do `new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(0)`, the integer value `0` is boxed to an `object` (because `int` is a value type). When WPF tries to use this default value, it tries to unbox it to a `double` (since the property is declared as `double`), which fails because the boxed value is an `int`, not a `double`. **A boxed value can only be unboxed to its actual type, the usual implicit numeric  conversions (like `int` to `double`) don't work in this case.**

Here's an example that illustrates the problem:

```
int i = 42;
double d1 = i; // Works fine, uses the built-in conversion from int to double
object o = i; // boxing
double d2 = (double)o; // Fails: unboxing to the wrong type
```

The compiler doesn't know statically that the object is actually a boxed int, so it can't use the built-in conversion; all it can do is unbox the value to the type specified by the developer.

Answer (score 4):

You are not doing a (simple) assignment. The default value is stored as a reference (boxed int) and later the property tries to get the default value as the specified type (double). In short, this code is equivalent :

```
 object x = 1;          // boxed int
 double d = (double)x;  // InvalidCast exception
```

The solution is of course simple:

```
 object x = 1.0;        // boxed double
 double d = (double)x;  // OK
```